# How Publish an NPM Package that Controls a CLI Keyword

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line

I'm not sure what the correct vocabulary is to even search for this question, but I can mention a couple packages that implement the pattern I'm trying to pick up:

1. `shx`
2. `cross-env`
3. `npm-run`

Once you install any of those packages, they are available via CLI. After I install `cross-env` as a dependency for a new project, for example, I can create an npm script in my `package.json` which is like `"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack"`

I inspected the `package.json` files for those projects and they all use the `bin` field, but if I initialize a local project (`npm init`) and add a bin field it doesn't recognize it on my command line, even after running `npm install`.

So how can I get that same functionality? Please also let me know if the question is clear or if I should add some other information.

My `package.json` is below:

```
{
  "name": "sloth-cli",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a dead simple Chron cli tool for Node",
  "bin": {
    "sloth": "node ."
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ."
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Vandivier/sloth.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "chron"
  ],
  "author": "John Vandivier",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Vandivier/sloth/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Vandivier/sloth#readme"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually discovered the answer and got [`sloth-cli`](https://github.com/Vandivier/sloth) working. `bin` in `package.json` is indeed key, but after defining bin we have to run `npm link` on our local.

In addition, the content of `bin` cannot contain typical npm script syntax. It must refer to a file which is set up to execute in a CLI context. This can be as simple as prepending `#! /usr/bin/env node` at the top of a javascript file.

Once a package is published to npm, those who install it as a dependency need not run `npm link`. Npm handles that part. Below is the current working `package.json` for `sloth-cli`:

```
{
  "name": "sloth-cli",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "a dead simple Chron cli tool for Node",
  "bin": {
    "sloth": "./index.js"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "immediately": "sloth .1 \"npm run say-hello\" true true",
    "start": "sloth .1 \"npm run say-hello\"",
    "say-hello": "node hello.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Vandivier/sloth.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "chron"
  ],
  "author": "John Vandivier",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Vandivier/sloth/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Vandivier/sloth#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "shelljs": "^0.8.1"
  }
}
```